# Relation between the orders of elements in minimal generating sets and the order of abelian group

Tags: group-theory, group-presentation, dihedral-groups, combinatorial-group-theory

The dihedral group has the following presentation $$D_{2i}=\left<s,r\mid s^2=r^i=e,sr=r^{-1}s \right>.$$

The order of $D_{2i}$ is $2i$.  If we take $S=\{s,r\}$ and $H=\{s,sr\}$, then  $D_{2i}=\left<S \right>=\left<H\right>$, but the sum the orders of elements of $S$ is $2+i$ and of $H$ is $4$. From this we deduce that there is no relation between the order of the non-abelian group and the orders of elements in minimal generating set.

My question is there any relation between the order of **abelian** group and the order of elements in its minimal generating sets?

Comment: I don't understand why you are taking the sum of orders of the elements in $S$ and $H$. In general for a group of finite order the order of any of its elements always divides the order of the group.

Comment: I'm working on new types of graphs that is related to groups ( like Cayley graph), the number of vertices in it is related to the order of the elements in minimal generating sets.

Answer (score 0):

The Structure Theorem for finitely-generated modules over a principal ideal domain (in one of its forms) seems to suggest that if $G$ is a finite abelian group, then the product of the orders of elements in a minimal generating set is equal to the order of the group. However, I think care needs to be taken. e.g. $C_{10}\times C_2$ is obviously generated by $(1,0), (0,1)$ which have orders ten and two, respectively, but it is also generated by $(1,0),(2,1)$, which both have order ten. Thus I think that the condition of a minimal generating set is not strong enough to determine the order of a group.